# getPoints() method in KineticJS is undefined

Tags: line, kineticjs

I want to implement a solution that allows me to draw `Kinetic.Line` with the mouse. My problem is that when I copy-paste my code in a .html file, and although everything works okay in the fiddle, I get this error:

```
TypeError: line.getPoints(...)[1] is undefined
```

This is the code I wrote, inspired by some jsfiddles and questions found in SO : http://jsfiddle.net/pg4fm/ What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm using two KineticJS libraries (v4.7.2 along with v5.0.1) because `getPoints()` method doesn't work in the v5.0.1. And I need the v5 for other purposes (other functions)

**EDIT :**
This fiddle now work http://jsfiddle.net/pg4fm/2/ But I still need the lines to be straight, just like in the first fiddle

Comment: Off topic, but are you experiencing odd results since you are loading 2 versions of KineticJS at the same time?

Comment: I know it's bad habit to load 2 versions, but as I explained, the v5 apparently modified the getPoints() method.

Comment: Fair enough...Could you instead use v5's line.points() to get your points array? Cheers!

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried but didn't work jsfiddle.net/pg4fm/1

Comment: EDIT: please see edited question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From v5.0.0 KineticJS return points in other way (see [docs](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Line.html#points)):

```
line.getPoints()
>> [x1, y1, x2, y2]
```

So. It is array of numbers, not objects. [Your updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pg4fm/3/).

Comment: So the method is `points()`. I used your fiddle and replaced the old method and deleted the old version of kineticJS (now there's only the v5.0.1) http://jsfiddle.net/pg4fm/1/ but still does not work :-(

Comment: I updated link. You can not do this `points()[0].x`, because `points()[0]` is a `number` not an object! Also you may use `getPoints()` in v5.0.0